# How to find a matrix of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V = \text{span}\{(1, 1, 1),(-1, 1, 2)\}$, and let $T:\Bbb R^3 \mapsto\Bbb R^3$ be the linear transformation given by the orthogonal projection onto $V$. What is the standard matrix of $T$? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=(x,y,z)\in V^\perp$ then we have using the inner product:

$$x+y+z=-x+y+2z=0$$
so by letting $z=2$ we find $y=-3$ and $x=1$ hence we normalize and we have 
$$u=\frac1{\sqrt{14}}(1,-3,2)$$
is a unit vector and  $V^\perp=\langle u\rangle$. Now the projection matrix on to $V^\perp$ is
$$P_{V^\perp}=\frac{1}{14}\left(\begin{matrix}1&-3&2\\-3&9&-6\\2&-6&4\end{matrix}\right)$$
and finally since
$$P_V+P_{V^\perp}=I_3$$
the result follows.

Comment: Could you briefly explain x+y+z=-x+y+2z=0 part?  I am quite confused. Thanks

Comment: The vector $u=(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ so using the inner product we have $x+y+z=0$. Use the same idea for the second vector $(-1,1,2)$.